# How to create a function that returns a pre-processed data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a function that takes accepts as input a data frame, the y-columns, and a list of x columns. The function should then pre-process the data by performing: 1) mean subtraction from y, and 2) dimension standardization for x. It should then return a pre-processed data frame with only the listed x and y columns.

Here is what I have so far. The problem is that my function returns the original raw data frame. How can I get my function to return what I need?

```
def preprocess_for_regularization(data, y_column_name, x_column_names):
    
    for i in data[y_column_name]:
        i -= (sum(data[y_column_name])/len(data[y_column_name]))
        
    for col in x_column_names:
        for j in data[col]:
            j = (j - (sum(data[col])/len(data[col])))/(std(num_list,ddof=0))
    return data

data = pd.read_csv(tr_path).head()
prepro_data = preprocess_for_regularization(data,'SalePrice', ['GrLivArea','YearBuilt'])
print(prepro_data)
```

Here is the output at the moment:

[image]

Comment: it does not look like i and j get assigned to anything. I can't see your data output but take a look at your loops. I and j get given values but don't get added back to your dataframe or returned.

Comment: The output is the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to modify the user-defined function:

```
def preprocess_for_regularization(data, y_column_name, x_column_names):
    
    data[y_column_name] = [(i - (sum(data[y_column_name])/len(data[y_column_name]))) for i in data[y_column_name]]
    
    for col in x_column_names:
        data[col] = [(j - (sum(data[col])/len(data[col])))/(std(data[col],ddof=0)) for j in data[col]]
     
    all_columns = x_column_names + [y_column_name]

    new_data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=all_columns)

    return new_data
```